# Installing external or unverified packages with Pip on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, pip

I'm attempting to deploy a Django application to Elastic Beanstalk. When it comes to installing from `requirements.txt`, Python complains that some of my requirements require the `--allow-external` or `--allow-unverified` flags.

How do I set these flags in the configuration file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the latest (1.5.6) documentation [Requirements File Format](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#requirements-file-format):

> Additionally, the following Package Index Options are supported:
>
> ```
> -i, -–index-url
> –-extra-index-url
> –-no-index
> -f, -–find-links
> -–allow-external
> -–allow-all-external
> -–allow-unverified
> ```

So you can just specify `–-allow-unverified`, `-–allow-external`.

Following is the example requirements file that use `--allow-unverified`:

```
–-allow-unverified pyXML
pyXML
```